# Connecting Android to PC so I can talk from PC?

Tags: hardware, microphone, speaker

Can I connect Nexus 5 to PC using wires, so I can talk from PC?

I have a 3.5mm-1-TRS(3ring)-female to 2-TRRS(4rings)-male-cable. (Don't know how to call it, sorry.)

After connecting LINE-in and Speakers port to the phone, I can hear sound from headphone on PC.

but my voice doesn't seem to go into Android.

Comment: Nothing in this set-up is Android-specific, so just try the usual debugging steps on your PC: if you talk to the PC with speakers plugged into the speaker output, does the sound come out? You might need to be careful about whether the cable connected to the mic part of the adapter is mono (TS) or stereo (TRS).

Comment: Thanks, Dan. Yes. It does work. Computer is fine. Computer side output is stereo, and phone side is mono. I'm trying to connect it as if the phone thinks the computer is 'microphone'. Doesn't it work?